# Entrust Permission Update Not Saving In Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 installation, which I have added both [Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) and [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) packages.

I am trying to build an admin interface to manage users, roles, and permissions.
I have created a resourceful controller for permissions and both the add and destroy functions work fine, but the edit does not. The record is not updating the values in the database.

Here is the code for my controller:

```
<?php

class PermissionController extends BaseController {

     protected $permission;

     public function __construct(Permission $permission)
    {
        $this->permission = $permission;
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $permission = $this->permission->find($id);

        if (is_null($permission))
        {
            return Redirect::route('permissions.index');
        }

        return View::make('permissions.edit', compact('permission'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Permission::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            $permission = $this->permission->find($id);
            // create name from display_name
            $input['name'] = $this->_machine_str($input['display_name']);

            try {
                $permission->update($input);
                $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
                $last_query = end($queries);
                print_r($queries);
                die();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
                die();
            }


            return Redirect::route('permissions.show', $id);
        }

        return Redirect::route('permissions.edit', $id)
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
    }

    ...
}
```

And the model:

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustPermission;

class Permission extends EntrustPermission
{
    /**
     *Soft delete enabled.
     * 
     * @var boolean 
     */
    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    /**
     * Ardent validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = array(
      'display_name' => 'required|between:4,32'
    );
}
```

The update works if I chnage the model to extend [Eloquent](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent), so I might be something to do with the EntrustPermission model.

I have also checked the database calls, which only show the selecting not any kind of update.

Comment: Do you get an error? Try setting the variables in Permission manually, and then using `save()`, rather than using `update($input)` and passing the array of arguments.

Comment: @fideloper you are right. Setting the values worked, still am mifted that the update() method isn't working correctly.

Comment: As the section in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete) which mentions the `update()` method is under the headline **Saving A Model And Relationships**, I'm assuming it's for saving relationship models, and is simply not documented clearly. Not 100% sure.

Comment: @fideloper if you write this all up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Surely, thanks - will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [section in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete) which mentions the `update()` method is under the headline **Saving A Model And Relationships**, I'm assuming the `update()` method is best used for updating a model's relationships and is simply not documented clearly.

If you instead take a "more manual" approach in updating the `Permission` model's attributes and using the `save()` method, you might have more success:

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
    $validation = Validator::make($input, Permission::$rules);

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $permission = $this->permission->find($id);
        // create name from display_name
        $input['name'] = $this->_machine_str($input['display_name']);

        try {
            // Change to update attributes "manually"
            $permission->name = $input['name'];

            // Update any other attributes as necessary
            $permission->any_other_attributes = $input['any_other_attributes']; // or  Input::get('any_other_attributes')

            // Finally, save (aka update) the Permission model's changes
            $permission->save();

            $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
            $last_query = end($queries);
            print_r($queries);
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
            die();
        }


        return Redirect::route('permissions.show', $id);
    }

    return Redirect::route('permissions.edit', $id)
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```